# Law of total expectation?

Tags: probability, number-theory, expectation, proof-explanation

Apparently $E[X] = E[E[X\mid Y]]$ but I don't understand what this really means. I looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation but need another explanation.

Isn't this the same as $E[X] = E[X\mid Y]$? Why the extra $E[ \cdot ]$? And ultimately why does the $Y$ not seem to even matter if we say that $X$ depends on $Y$?

Comment: $E[X|Y]$ is a random variable with respect to $Y$.

Comment: Wait a sec, so $E[X]$ is a constant, but $E[X|Y]$ is not? And even so why does the expected value of that equal $E[X]$ without taking $Y$ into account?

Comment: Well $E[X|Y=a]$ and $E[X|Y=b]$ may be different if $a\neq b$.

Comment: Oh, so it's basically saying the expected value of $X$ over all the possible values of $Y$?

Comment: $E[X|Y](\omega)=E[X|Y=Y (omega)] $. For each fixed value of $Y $ it is just a constant.

Comment: $E[X \mid Y]$ is generally an expression in terms of $Y$ (that is, $E[X \mid Y = y]$ is an expression in terms of $y$).  Taking the average of these expectations over all values of $Y$ gives you the overall $E[X]$.

Comment: Does this assume any kind of linkage between $X$ and $Y$? For example if I were to say... I dunno, $X$ = value from a six-sided die, and $Y=$ today's weather, would it still work?

Comment: Another way to write your fact is that
$$
E_Y\left[ E_X[X \mid Y] \right] = E_X[X]
$$
where $E_Y$ means "the expectation over all $Y$".

Comment: Yes it still works if they are independent because then $E[X|Y=y]=E[X]$ for all values of $y$.

Comment: So like E(X|Y) = E(X|y=rainy)*P(rainy) + E(X|y=sunny)*P(sunny) = E(X)*P(rainy) + E(X)*P(sunny) + E(X)*(P(rainy) + P(sunny)) = E(X)*1 = E(X)?

Comment: @user6596353 There is no such assumption, but the results are "trivial" if $X$ and $Y$ are independent events.  For your example, we would always have
$$
E[X \mid Y] = 3.5
$$
$E[X \mid Y]$ is technically "a function of $Y$", it just happens to be a constant function.

Comment: Do we always assume that E(X|Y=something) = E(X | something is true) * P(something being true)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$The random variable $X$ has a conditional probability distribution given the event $Y=y$, for each value $y$ that the random variable $Y$ can take.  Hence it also has a conditional expected value $\E(X\mid Y=y)$.  This conditional expected value of course depends on $y$; thus we can write $\E(X\mid Y=y) = g(y)$.

The $g(Y)$ is a random variable, and we denote it $\E(X\mid Y)$.

As a concrete example, suppose five red marbles and three green marbles are in an urn, and you draw two of them without replacement.  Let $Y$ be the number of red marbles on the first draw (either $0$ or $1$) and $X$ on the second.  Then
$$
Y = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{with probability } \dfrac 3 8, \\[6pt]
1 & \text{with probability } \dfrac 5 8. \end{cases}
$$

\begin{align}
\E(X\mid Y=0) & = \frac 5 7. \\[10pt]
\E(X\mid Y=1) & = \frac 4 7.
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
\E(X\mid Y) = \begin{cases} \dfrac 5 7 & \text{with probability } \dfrac 3 8, \\[6pt]
\dfrac 4 7 & \text{with probability } \dfrac 5 8. \end{cases}
$$
That's what $\E(X\mid Y)$ means.  And with that probabilty distribution of the random variable $\E(X\mid Y)$, you can find $\E(\E(X\mid Y))$.

Answer (score 0):

A concrete example:

Suppose $X$ can take the values $0$ or $1$. Suppose $Y$ can take the values $a$ or $b$ each with probability $1/2$. Suppose that if $Y=a$ then the probability $X=0$ is $1$ while if $Y=b$ then the probability $X=0$ is $0$. Then $E[X\mid Y=a]=0$ while $E[X\mid Y=b]=1$. Then $$E[X]=E[E[X\mid Y]]=\frac{1}{2}E[X\mid Y=a]+\frac{1}{2}E[X\mid Y=b]=\frac{1}{2}0+\frac{1}{2}1=\frac{1}{2}.$$

You can see that $Y$ "disappears" because when you take the expectation of $E[X\mid Y]$ you are just weighting the conditional expectations of $X$ given each $Y$ by the probability of that value of $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a pair of variates $(X,Y)$ variate defined by the following process:

Roll one six-sided die; call the result $Y$.  Then roll $X$ six-sided dice and call the sum of the pips $X$.

Now $E[X\mid Y]$ will be given by $\frac72 Y$; for example, if the $Y$ roll was a $2$, then by rolling two dice you get an expected value of $7$ for $X$ -- this is $E[X\mid Y=2]$.  If $Y$ is something else, $k$, then $E[X\mid Y=k]$ will be different.

How would we calculate the overall $E[X]$? Well, $\frac16$ of the time $Y$ will be $1$ and then $E[X]$ would be $\frac72$ for those cases.  And $\frac16$ of the time $Y$ will be $2$ and then $E[X]$ would be $7$ for those cases.  and so forth.  Adding those up, what you have done is taken the expectation (over possible values of $Y$ of the expectation of $X$ given each value of $Y$.  And that is what your statement says.

BTW, the answer for this simple problem is $\frac{49}{4}$

Comment: "Then roll X six-sided dice and call the sum of the pips X" Do you mean rolling Y times?